# Cycle on list using parallelism in Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, parallel-processing, databricks

I'm tring to cycle trough a list of dictionaries on Databricks. This is my code that I'm using . The goal is to read information stored in the list, do some transformation and then write on cassandra db.

```
def update_campaing_headcounter_sum(headcounter_info: dict):
    yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1)
    yesterday = yesterday.date()

   
    timestamp_inf = headcounter_info['startDate'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")
    timestamo_sup = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00")
    device_id = headcounter_info['DeviceId']
    headcounter_id = headcounter_info['HeadcounterId']
    campaign_id = headcounter_info['CampaignId']
    print('-------')
    for category in ['PERSON','VEHICLE']:
        print(category)
        new_base_values = compute_new_base_values(timestamp_inf, timestamo_sup, device_id, category, cassandra_manager_prod)
        temp_sum_headcounter_category_df = get_cassandra_sum(campaign_id, headcounter_id, category, cassandra_manager_dev)
        new_temp_headcounter_category_df = (temp_sum_headcounter_category_df
                                            .withColumn('base_ots',new_base_values['BaseOts']- F.col('base_ots'))
                                            .withColumn('base_views',new_base_values['BaseViews']- F.col('base_views'))
                                            .withColumn('base_dwell_milliseconds',new_base_values['BaseDwellTimeMilliseconds']- F.col('base_dwell_milliseconds'))
                                            .withColumn('base_attention_milliseconds',new_base_values['BaseAttentionTimeMilliseconds'] - F.col('base_attention_milliseconds'))
                                            ).select('campaign_id','headcounter_id','category','base_ots', 'base_views','base_dwell_milliseconds','base_attention_milliseconds')
        write_on_cassandra(temp_sum_headcounter_category_df)
    return headcounter_info

hc_info_from_active_campaign_list = get_hc_info_from_active_campaign().rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict()).collect()
print('--------')
rdd_list = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(hc_info_from_active_campaign_list)

rdd_result = rdd_list.map(update_campaing_headcounter_sum)
result = rdd_result.collect()
```

To understand the basics i tried this very simple function:

```
def my_func(headcounter_info: dict):
   print(headcounter_info)
   return headcounter_info
```

the return statment is used only becouse I read that is mandatory for the rdd.map function. I also tried with the rdd.foreach but nothing changes. It's like nothing happens even if the code has no error, or at least databricks does not acknowledge anything. The simple function does not print anything, just like everything I tried putting insiede the function update_campaing_headcounter_sum.

I was using a single node cluster on Databricks and then created a new cluster with one driver and one worker, but this didn't helped.

Comment: Why do you need to use RDD API in first place? Can you describe what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I Extract key values from SQL server and put them in a list of dictionaries, with every dictionaries used for get data of "Headcounters" from cassandra, apply some logic and then write again on cassandra. I cannot do column wise operation given query on cassandra based on differnet timestamp gap. I need to parallelize the operation over the list of dictionaries given the size of the initial list